# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, class, fatal-error

I'm having big problems with this fatal error. I have 5 files and every of them contains one class (Nationality.php, Team.php, BoughtTickets.php, Users.php, Tickets.php) and two of them require other classes.

So here is index.php

```
<?php

require 'header.html';
require 'pages/first.html';
require 'class/db.php';

$c=DB::connect();

require 'pages/footer.html';
?>
```

---

Users.php

```
require 'Nationality.php';
require 'Team.php';
require 'BoughtTickets.php';

class Users{
    public $Email;
    public $Name;
    ...
```

---

BoughtTickets.php

```
require 'Tickets.php';

class BoughtTicket{

    public $IDTicket;
    public $Date;
    ...
```

Eveytime I want to login, it gives me fatal error. If I remove line require 'BoughtTickets.php'; from class Users, it works, but it won't display table in one file which requires class BoughtTickets.php. Do you have any idea what to do to solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: `require_once('....')` is your friend. Also, `if(!class_exists('BoughtTicket')): require('BoughtTickets.php'); endif;` is sufficient as well.

Comment: This is a programming question, `its not working` lacks sufficient information to attempt to answer this question. What is occuring when using `require_once()` or `if(!class_exists('...'))`

Comment: It's the same error as earlier: 
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Ticket.php

Comment: Then your `require_once()` statements aren't working right. Better yet, why not just look into using `namespacing`?

Comment: I found a solution. There was mistake with requiring a class in a different file. So `require_once()` actually solved a problem in the end. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `require_once` instead of `require`

Answer (score 0):

You may come across this error if you have something like

```
class C
{
}

class B extends A
{
}

class A
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with include_once instead of require.